# French equivalent of the Japanese expression 黄色い声援, "let out a yellow cheer"

Tags: expressions, japonais

In Japanese, we use the expression 黄色い声援, "*(let out) a **yellow** cheer*" to describe a collective ecstatic exclamation that extremely enthusiastic female fans utter at the sight of a famous actor or the performance of their favourite band.

This expression is confined to denoting ***females*** who, fangirling over their idol, burst out cheering and screaming wildly. Your guess is as good as mine, though, as to why we use the colour *yellow*.

An audience letting out a yellow cheer, 黄色い声援: [羽生結弦　アスリートの魂 (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/jrFxZVViA_I?t=463).

Comment: The link is not available in my country (United States). Don't know about others.

Comment: The link is fine in Canada.

Answer (score 7):

I would say "des admiratrices en liesse"

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that usually referred to with some variation of *hystérie*?

Answer (score 0):

While Fred's answer is nice, I would suggest *des groupies en liesse* which is less formal and emphasis on the fangirls in concerts.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "Hystérie" is more convenient than "en liesse" which means high  joy but without madness. 
Yellow was the color of jester and insanes.

Close to that, i should say :
  "un public en délire" or "des groupies en délire" if restricted to women.